# Numeric Sort with string

Tags: php, sorting

I checked numeric sort with this:

```
$fruits = array("c","b","a", "11",100, 100,"10",  );
sort($fruits, SORT_NUMERIC);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo $val."<br>";
}
```

And output is
c
b
A
a
10
11
100
100

Why it is showing c above b ?

Answer (score 0):

Numeric sort means it sorts array based on thair ascci values
 following are ascii values of your array
c ascii: 99
b ascii: 98
a ascii: 97
11 ascii: 49
10 ascii; 49
100 ascii: 49
100 ascii : 49

Answer (score 0):

If you are using only alphabetic and numeric value, you can use following code:

```
 <?php
  $fruits = array("c","b","a", "11",100, 100,"10");
    natsort($fruits);
    $numarray = array();
    $strarray = array();
    foreach ($fruits as $key => $value) {
            // $array[] = $value;
            if(is_numeric($value)){
                    $numarray[] = $value;
            }
            else {
                    $strarray[] = $value;
            }
    }
    $array = array_merge($strarray,$numarray);
    // print_r($array);
    foreach ($array as $key1 => $val) {
        echo $val."<br>";
    }
 ?>
```

Hope this helps!